# How can I get a single row on a inner join not to double my sum

Tags: join, oracle-11g, group-by, sum

I have two tables (DEP_DEZ & CAR_EXP):

```
ID  FK_ID_CHESTIONAR    TOTAL_E TOTAL_F TOTAL_STOC
261 644                 87      152     48

ID  MASA_TOTALA FK_ID_CHESTIONAR
405 20          644
406 45          644
```

if I make an:

```
SELECT CHT.ID,
       SUM(DEP_DEZ.TOTAL_E+DEP_DEZ.TOTAL_F+DEP_DEZ.TOTAL_STOC)
       FROM CHEST cht
            INNER JOIN DEP_DEZ
               ON DEP_DEZ.FK_ID_CHESTIONAR = CHT.ID
   GROUP BY CHT.ID
```

The result is 644 and 287 (87+152+48). And it is ok, but if I make:

```
SELECT CHT.ID,
       SUM(DEP_DEZ.TOTAL_E+DEP_DEZ.TOTAL_F+DEP_DEZ.TOTAL_STOC),
       SUM(CAR_EXP.MASA_TOTALA),
       FROM CHEST cht
            INNER JOIN DEP_DEZ
               ON DEP_DEZ.FK_ID_CHESTIONAR = CHT.ID
            INNER JOIN CAR_EXP
               ON CAR_EXP.FK_ID_CHESTIONAR = CHT.ID
   GROUP BY CHT.ID
```

the result is 644 and 574 (287*2 - not ok) and 65 (45+20 - ok)

How can I make not to double my "287" in sum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use multiple SELECT Statements, like this:

```
SELECT CHT.ID,
   (SELECT SUM(TOTAL_E + TOTAL_F + TOTAL_STOC) 
   FROM DEP_DEZ WHERE FK_ID_CHESTIONAR = cht.ID),
   (SELECT SUM(MASA_TOTALA) FROM CAR_EXP WHERE FK_ID_CHESTIONAR = CHT.ID)
   FROM CHEST cht
GROUP BY CHT.ID
```

Comment: It works, but what if I want to add SUM(MASA_TOTALA) to SUM(TOTAL_E + TOTAL_F + TOTAL_STOC)?

Comment: You can even sum both SELECT.
(SELECT1) +  (SELECT2).  With SELECT1 I'm meaning SUM DEP_DEZ and SELECT2 is SUM CAR_EXP.

Comment: I tried SUM((SELECT SUM(TOTAL_E+TOTAL_F+TOTAL_STOC) 
                FROM DEP_DEZ
                WHERE FK_ID_CHESTIONAR = CHT.ID)+
       (SELECT SUM(MASA_TOTALA) 
                FROM CAR_EXP
                WHERE FK_ID_CHESTIONAR = CHT.ID)) but it gives me an 704

Comment: (SELECT SUM(TOTAL_E+TOTAL_F+TOTAL_STOC) FROM DEP_DEZ WHERE FK_ID_CHESTIONAR = CHT.ID)     +        (SELECT SUM(MASA_TOTALA) FROM CAR_EXP WHERE FK_ID_CHESTIONAR = CHT.ID)